# check login curl php

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem when I try the code to verify the connection, he said OK whatever connection password or username

```
<?php
$lien = 'http://fr.openclassrooms.com/login';
$postfields = array(
    'username' => 'xxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',

);


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if (!preg_match('#Votre login ou votre mot de passe est incorrect. #i', $return))
{
    echo 'Connexion ok.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Connexion aground.';
}
?>
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: need to see your login code

Comment: Expliquez votre problem

Comment: The string `Votre login ou votre mot de passe est incorrect. ` doesn't appear on the page. Check the contents of `$return`, the page contents may not be the same as within a browser.

Comment: You're also posting the form to the wrong URL, it should be `/login_check` not `/login`. `login_check` does a 302 redirect.